# Черный копатель и археолог. В кавычках?

Tags: пунктуация

Черный копатель и археолог. В кавычках?

Comment: Зачем дублировать текст? Есть ли тут скрытый смысл?

Answer (score 1):

**Эти выражения могут писаться в кавычках или без кавычек в зависимости от текста.**

В специальных текстах на эту тему кавычек нет, так как читателю это понятие знакомо. В других же случаях (для общей аудитории) употребление кавычек возможно, причем иногда сначала кавычки пишутся, а потом опускаются.

**Из Википедии:** Чёрные копатели — ставшее традиционным собирательное название для самодеятельных поисковиков различных направлений, одиночек или организованных в группы, занимающихся нелегальным выкапыванием различных предметов старины.

Черные копатели — это собирательное название. Сами копатели подразделяют себя на кладоискателей, трофейщиков и чёрных археологов.

Пример: Кто такие "черные копатели" (название).

И далее: Кто же они, чёрные копатели, попытаемся разобраться. В среде "черных следопытов" существует своя иерархия (новый термин уже написан  в кавычках).

Розенталь: Употребление кавычек [§ 59. Слова, употребляемые в необычном, условном, ироническом значении](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=169#pp169)

8) слова, употребленные **в условном значении** (применительно к ситуации или контексту): На манёврах «красные» выступали против «зелёных» [Газ.];  Встреча «Большой семёрки» (семь крупнейших стран); Солидный «урожай» олимпийских наград собрали наши спортсмены; Завоевать «золото», разделить «серебро», ограничиться «бронзой» (в спортивной печати); Политические обозреватели за «круглым столом».

**По мере того как подобные выражения становятся обиходными, в кавычки они заключаются все реже.** Например, стали писать без кавычек: часы пик; голосовать за и против; работать на отлично; Большая восьмёрка и др.